# Is it possible to change the behavior in view of existing apps after new app is installed with touching the existing apps?

Tags: django, django-views

Let's take an example of two apps:

- Stock
- StockBalance

So IceCream was developed first, and all the views are Stock are created using the generic Class-Based Views - SListView, SCreateView,SDetailView, SUpdateView and SDeleteView. And the URL mapping are as follows:

- /stock/ - SListView
- /stock/new - SCreateView
- /stock/(id) - SDetailView
- /stock/(id)/edit - SUpdateView
- /stock/(id)/delete - SDeleteView

And later StockBalance is being developed. Without touching the code from the Stock app, how can I change the behavior of the each view? And what is the common method in Django to do that?

What I want to archieve is that:

- When user visits /stock/new , he would be able to create a new stock with the initial stock balance.
- When user visits /stock/(id) , he would be able to read the stock detail as well as the stock balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the URL mappings of StockBalance in front of those of Stock. This ensures those URLs will be found first by Django and thus you can fully reimplement (inherit / override / etc) what those views will do.

So:

- /stock/new = implemented by new app
- /stock/{id} = implemented by new app
- /stock/... = all others, as before

Comment: Ya. Marking your answer as correct. I actually have a more complicated situation and I forgot about that.

What if I have a third app called StockPrice. So:
 - If StockPrice is added, /stock/new/ should allows creation of stock and stockprice.
 - If StockBalance is added, /stock/new/ should allows creation of stock and stockbalance.
 - If both are added, /stock/new should allows creation of stock, stockprice and stockbalance.

For last use case, is creation of a new app required? Since neither stockprice or stockbalance will know if others is installed.

Comment: @JohanSJA in theory that should be possible by doing introspection about what apps are currently installed. The logic for /new/ could remain the same and it could support whatever apps you wish to include.